# Solution for Dividing WorkSheet into Multiple Files with vba/excel/c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

I would like to divide a worksheet into multiple files.

I have a worksheet with about 10,000 rows. there is fancy formatting, conditional formatting, nice colors, and I want to preserve all of these attributes.

I need to divide this worksheet up.

the input would be:

```
+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Alex  | 45 |  6 | 23 | 56 |
| Alex  | 61 | 47 | 56 | 56 |
| Liza  | 49 | 70 | 34 | 37 |
| Alex  | 33 | 30 | 22 | 39 |
| Tommy |    | 66 | 62 | 29 |
| Liza  |    | 38 | 49 | 80 |
| Alex  | 23 | 56 | 56 | 39 |
| Liza  | 32 | 46 | 40 | 43 |
| Liza  |    | 90 | 24 | 38 |
| Tommy | 38 | 10 | 52 | 23 |
| Nancy | 35 | 36 | 23 | 25 |
+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

and the output would be separate files like this (please keep in mind i want to preserve all the fancy formatting, and thus the solution has work directly with excel, and not with just CSV (because csv cannot retain formatting))

end products:

```
+------+----+----+----+----+
|      |    |    |    |    |
| Alex | 45 |  6 | 23 | 56 |
| Alex | 61 | 47 | 56 | 56 |
| Alex | 33 | 30 | 22 | 39 |
| Alex | 23 | 56 | 56 | 39 |
+------+----+----+----+----+
```

and

```
+------+----+----+----+----+
|      |    |    |    |    |
| Liza | 49 | 70 | 34 | 37 |
| Liza |    | 38 | 49 | 80 |
| Liza | 32 | 46 | 40 | 43 |
| Liza |    | 90 | 24 | 38 |
+------+----+----+----+----+
```

and

```
+-------+----+----+----+----+
|       |    |    |    |    |
| Nancy | 35 | 36 | 23 | 25 |
+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

and

```
+-------+----+----+----+----+
|       |    |    |    |    |
| Tommy |    | 66 | 62 | 29 |
| Tommy | 38 | 10 | 52 | 23 |
+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

the solution can be a combination of VBA/.NET. please note that i need  multiple files as outputs.

what is the quickest way to get this working? thanks so much for any input!

please note that this is excel 2007 and later

Comment: Is this an Excel 2003 & earlier .xls file, or an Excel 2007 & later .xlsx file?

Comment: @CharlieKilian it's 2007 and later

Comment: @CharlieKilian but i guess i can just save as 2003

Comment: Do you know enough VBA to do this? (Are you looking for guidance or a solution?)

Comment: @mick i know that this is possible wiht VBA, but i would like to know if there is a simple c# solution, and if only using VBA then, can you please tell me how would i split up based on the UNIQUE values in the column?

Comment: Is preserving the current order within each sub-set important?

Comment: Is this something you need to do one time, or do you need it as part of a routine automated process? If one time, I suggest Petr's answer below. If you want an automated process, I may have some suggestions.

Comment: i will need to automate it, but it's ok if it's very inefficient because there wont be more than a couple hundred files created each time

Comment: @CharlieKilian would love to hear ur suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Since Excel formatting is usually a big pain in the a**, I would recommend to try a following solution:

1. Calculate and store all the unique keys.
2. Create a copy of a file for each key (like `file_Alex.xls[x]`, `file_Liza.xls[x]` and so on).
3. Process each file, deleting all non-key rows, thus all key entries are left. Also because you are only deleting entire rows all the formatting in file is retained.

This is very unoptimized, but also extremely simple solution. If it's a one-time job, it should do just fine.

Comment: this looks awesome. can you please elaborate on #3, what is the logic here?

Comment: @I__ well, you remove entire rows which is a non-key for given file, leaving only key-match row. Thus all the formatting is retained.

Comment: i reread this and this looks pretty awesome, i think i will try it right now

Answer (score 2):

I done this before.

You can use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getInformations()

Dim varName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Replace Tabelle1 with the name of your sheet where the Informations are
Worksheets("Tabelle1").Select
Worksheets("Tabelle1").Copy After:=Sheets("Tabelle1")
Sheets("Tabelle1 (2)").Select
Sheets("Tabelle1 (2)").Name = "Temp"
Do Until Range("A1").Value = vbNullString
    varName = Range("A1").Value
    Workbooks.Add
    'Change the Path where you want to save the File
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Documents and Settings\vgellhom\Desktop\" & varName & ".xls")
    'Change The Name of the Excel Workbopk to the Name of the Workbook with the Names
    Workbooks("Data.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    varName = Range("A1").Value

    Do While True
        Cells.Find(What:=varName).Activate
        Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks(varName & ".xls").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        'Change The Name of the Excel Workbopk to the Name of the Workbook with the Names
        Workbooks("Data.xls").Activate
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        If Not Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then
            Cells.Find(What:=varName).Activate
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Workbooks(varName & ".xls").Activate
    'Change the Path where you want to save the File
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Workbooks(varName & ".xls").Close
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope that helps you...

Comment: This is very similar to the approach I was going to outline. +1 to Moosli.

Comment: @mossli thank you again. when you have a chance can you please help me understsand this code

Comment: what does this mean: 'Change The Name of the Excel Workbopk to the Name of the Workbook with the Names

Comment: You have a Excel file where are all the Names are in it. You have to exchange the "Data.xls" with that name!

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Sure i can.