# VBA macro to split one worksheet into several workbooks based on number of rows in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am sanitizing contact data in an excel spreadsheet in order to bulk upload into SalesForce.  SalesForce, however, can only manage worksheets 100 contacts long.  I want a macro that can split up a 700 row worksheet, for example, into seven workbooks, each containing 100 cell references.

I did some research on how to go about doing this, and I believe this is the only reference on StackOverflow to aid in this end:
[Solution for Dividing WorkSheet into Multiple Files with vba/excel/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934287/solution-for-dividing-worksheet-into-multiple-files-with-vba-excel-c)

Also, this solution looks promising, but I don't understand enough VBA to grasp it just yet: https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007

However, the selected answer doesn't really serve my ends.  Can someone point me in the right direction / enumerate the commands for doing this?

Here's what I have so far-- this appears to produce the right number of workbooks.  Now I just need to figure out how to cut and paste 100 rows into each one.

```
    Sub Macro12()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Double
    Dim p_quotient As Double
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    p = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    p_quotient = p / 100
    p_quotient = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(p_quotient, 0)

    For i = 1 To p_quotient
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "test" & i
        wb.Close

    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing


End Sub
```

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
Sub Macro12()

  Dim wb As Workbook
      Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
      Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
      Dim RangeToCopy As Range
      Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
      Dim myDate As String
      myDate = Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd")

      Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
      WorkbookCounter = 1


      For p = 1 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 101
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add

        Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + 100, NumOfColumns))
        RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Salesforce Lead Conversion " & myDate & " Part " & WorkbookCounter & ".xls"
        wb.Close
        WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
      Next p

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Set wb = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code you have used so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your logic, this should do it:

```
  Sub Macro12()

      Dim wb As Workbook
      Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
      Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
      Dim RangeToCopy As Range
      Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False


      Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
      WorkbookCounter = 1

      For p = 1 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 101
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add

        Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + 100, NumOfColumns))
        RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test" & WorkbookCounter
        wb.Close
        WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
      Next p

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Set wb = Nothing


  End Sub
```

Comment: This works well!  Unfortunately, I have two problems.  1.  The program produces five new spreadsheets, irrespective of the number of rows used in the program-- why is this?  2.  I have modified the Workbook SaveAs to look like this: wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Salesforce Lead Conversion " & myDate & " Part " & WorkbookCounter & ".xls"-- now, however, the file says it's corrupt.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the exact code you're using right now? I tested the code I gave you and it produced 8 workbooks when I had 725 rows. As for #2, it **might** be that myDate is formatted with "\" characters in it... You can't do that for a file name. But that's just a quick guess

Comment: I discovered the issue is that this code: ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, yields 435 for me, even when that row has not been used.  Going to try to find a substitute for that.  Smart idea with the myDate formatting

Comment: chaneg the `UsedRange` line to something more like this `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row()`

Answer (score 0):

Although there are MANY ways to do this (some even extremely easy with VBA) What I think would be the easiest that requires no VBA would be to do the following:

- Add in an extra "helper" column
- In that column, put in the following formula `=FLOOR(ROW()/100,1)`
- Do a filter on the data

Now, filter for each number 0,1,2,3,...,7 in your helper column.

Each set will have your next hundred records - Copy and paste them into a new workbook and save it as needed. Also, from this point it's TRULY a trivial case to record a quick macro to do that last part.

Even though it isn't exactly what you asked for, I hope the simplicity of it helps.

Comment: This helps, but I'm developing a macro toolbox for a company, and would prefer it be automated.